# Проблема с telebot + Django. Реально ли прикрутить telegram бота к Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, telegram, telebot

Пытаюсь связать телеграм бота и Django админку. Django модели описал. все работает, но вот бот не хочет стартовать! Подскажите, где я свернул не туда ? 
Я сэтнул вебхук на домен с сертификатом (https://mydomain.com/bot), в Django урлах прописал:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from bot import views as bot

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('bot/', bot.stuff),
]
```

Во views.py прописал следующее:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import telebot

@csrf_exempt
def stuff(message):
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(МОЙ ТОКЕН)
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def echo(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

    return HttpResponse("I`m not working like that!")
```

По началу я не прописывал декоратор @csrf_exempt, но без него getWebhookInfo возвращал 403 ошибку:

```
{"ok":true,
"result":{"url":"https://mydomain.com/bot/",
"has_custom_certificate":false,
"pending_update_count":1,
"last_error_date":1530615883,
"last_error_message":"Wrong response from the webhook: 403 Forbidden",
"max_connections":40}}
```

Но после добавления @csrf_exempt, ситуация отнюдь не ставновится радужной:

```
{"ok":true,"
result":{"url":"https://mydomain.com/bot/",
"has_custom_certificate":false,
"pending_update_count":0,
"last_error_date":1530616116,
"last_error_message":"Connection refused",
"max_connections":40}}
```

Почему вылазит Connection refused?
Прошу подсказать, что я сделал не так, и как вообще завести самого простого эхо бота. Буду очень благодарен за разъяснения и ссылки на материалы по теме

Comment: Connection refused означает, что запрос никто не принял — видимо, джанга просто выключена

Comment: @andreymal, я могу зайти в админку и тд, так что скорее всего проблема не в этом

Comment: https://github.com/jlmadurga/django-telegram-bot

Comment: Должны быть запущены: сервер-джанго и бот-сервис, дальше бросайте боту сообщение.

Answer (score 0):

Хочу заметить, что прим поведении вебхуке вам с хука приходит POST запрос, и я не совсем уверен , но по-моему вебхуке надо отдать Какой то конкретный ответ от сервера, но я не уверен, вообще бот на Джаггер это странный зато, в ней куча лишнего мусора, который никому  в данном случае не нужен гораздо легче прокрутить его например у flask, с ним вообще нет проблем, знаний для конкретно бота, нужно столько что за 20 мин. Гугления вы все успеете найти посмотрите на ютубе видео telegram бот с webhook за 2 часа, что то такое, там в начале есть все при то как его прокрутить к flask